# CentOS - bash version not changing after upgrade

Tags: bash, shell

Current bash version is vulnerable to shellshock. But upgrading doesn't change the bash. I've tried rebooting.

**CentOS version 5.6**

```
[user@server ~]$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.


[user@server ~]$ yum list bash
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
base/primary                                                                                                                                               | 1.2 MB     00:00
base                                                                                                                                                                    3566/3566
Installed Packages
bash.x86_64                3.2-32.el5      installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues:

1. CentOS 5 is out of support and there will be no security fixes for this anymore. Shellshock is only one of the security issues that likely affect this product at this point in time.
2. You are running a very old version of CentOS 5. The last released one is CentOS 5.11. At the very least, you should upgrade to this version, which also includes the fix for Shellshock.